# Pandas dataframe .dropna() is not dropping NaN values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a set of features:

> 'SalePrice', 'OverallQual', 'GrLivArea', 'GarageCars', 'TotalBsmtSF', 
>   'GarageArea', '1stFlrSF', 'FullBath', 'YearBuilt', 'TotRmsAbvGrd',
>   'YearRemodAdd', 'GarageYrBlt', 'Fireplaces', 'MasVnrArea', 'LotArea',
>   'LotFrontage', 'BsmtFinSF1', 'OpenPorchSF', 'WoodDeckSF', '2ndFlrSF',
>   'HalfBath', 'BsmtUnfSF', 'BsmtFullBath'

of which 3 features contain some NaN values. I would like to drop the rows with NaN values. To do so, I run

```
for item in features:
    train_data[item].dropna(inplace=True)
    print(train_data[item].isnull().values.any())
```

This gives the output:

```
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
False
```

This leads me to believe that all of the NaN values have been successfully dropped. However, when I then run

```
print(train_data[features].isnull().values.any())
```

Output:

```
True
```

My understanding was that by setting `inplace=True` that the dataframe would be manipulated in the current instance. However, when I inspect the `train_data[features]` after running the loop to drop null values, it is unchanged. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Using df=df.dropna(subset=features)

Comment: @W-B perfect, thank you! feel free to write it as an answer if you want me to accept it

Comment: Done with that , happy coding

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IIUC

```
df=df.dropna(subset=features)
```

Comment: What should be the type of features? I have one column of dataframe with nan

Comment: @FabioSpaghettiF features is the list of columns , in your case `df.dropna(subset=['col'])`

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti yw :-) happy coding